# Angular routerLink element has unexpected styling on load

Tags: css, angular

When a page is loaded (using the Angular router) any button on that page that uses `routerLink` has weird initial styling. The gif below says it best:

### [image]

The Add Person button works as expected, the element looks like this:

`<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openPersonModal()"> Add Person</button>`

The Add Company button has the odd initial styling, the element looks like this:

`<a class="btn btn-primary" routerlink="/company-add">Add Company</a>`

Any ideas?

Comment: can you repliciate this on stackblitz

Comment: add You css file

Comment: Have you checked how the element changes in the DOM when you click "All"?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same behaviour when route changes. Unexpected style flick is exactly the same as on your case.